# searching arraylist course info java (examtimetable)

Tags: java, database, class, search, arraylist

ok i have a timetable and i have all the courses in a data base and which is displayed when the data base is loaded i now need to search the array list and display all the course content on it. eg say i search math101 it shows me the course name, id#, type etc.... i need help with the search function.

```
package timetable;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExamTimeTableArrayList {

    public static class CourseInfo {

        private String courseCode;
        private String courseName;
        private String courseType;
        private String courseLevel;
        private String faculty;
        private String day;
        private int session;

        CourseInfo(String courseCode, String courseName, String courseType, String courseLevel, String faculty, String day, int session) {
            setCourseCode(courseCode);
            setCourseName(courseName);
            setCourseType(courseType);
            setCourseLevel(courseLevel);
            setFaculty(faculty);
            setDay(day);
            setSession(session);
        }

        public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
            this.courseCode = courseCode;
        }

        public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
            this.courseName = courseName;
        }

        public void setCourseType(String courseType) {
            this.courseType = courseType;
        }

        public void setCourseLevel(String courseLevel) {
            this.courseLevel = courseLevel;
        }

        public void setFaculty(String faculty) {
            this.faculty = faculty;
        }

        public void setDay(String day) {
            this.day = day;
        }

        public void setSession(int session) {
            this.session = session;
        }

        public String getCourseCode() {
            return courseCode;
        }

        public String getCourseName() {
            return courseName;
        }

        public String getCourseType() {
            return courseType;
        }

        public String getCourseLevel() {
            return courseLevel;
        }

        public String getFaculty() {
            return faculty;
        }

        public String getDay() {
            return day;
        }

        public int getSession() {
            return session;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new table().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        String Code;
        String Name;
        String Type;
        String Level;
        String Faculty;
        String Day;
        int Session;
        int ID;
        ArrayList<CourseInfo> array = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<CourseInfo> array2 = new ArrayList(); //Second array for comparison and search

        int x = 0;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Template.sqlite");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Database opened successfully");

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Template");
            while (rs.next()) {

                ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                Code = rs.getString("courseCode ");
                Name = rs.getString("courseName");
                Type = rs.getString("courseType");
                Level = rs.getString("courseLevel");
                Faculty = rs.getString("Faculty");
                Day = rs.getString("Day");
                Session = rs.getInt("Session");

                CourseInfo Exams = new CourseInfo(Code, Name, Type, Level, Faculty, Day, Session);
                Exams.setCourseCode(Code);
                Exams.setCourseName(Name);
                Exams.setCourseType(Type);
                Exams.setCourseLevel(Level);
                Exams.setFaculty(Faculty);
                Exams.setDay(Day);
                Exams.setSession(Session);

                array.add(Exams);
                x++;
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Operation done successfully");

        for (int i = 0; i < 102; i++) {
            CourseInfo Object = array.get(i);
            System.out.println("Course Code: " + Object.getCourseCode());
            System.out.println("Course Name: " + Object.getCourseName());
            System.out.println("Course Type: " + Object.getCourseType());
            System.out.println("Course Level:" + Object.getCourseLevel());
            System.out.println("Faculty: " + Object.getFaculty());
            System.out.println("Day: " + Object.getDay());
            System.out.println("Session: " + Object.getSession());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Come back when you have something more specific than "can anyone help?" with no explanation as to what. Also, cut down your code to the smallest reproduce-able size

Comment: i need to search the arraylist for courses and i want it to display everything for that said course

Comment: Ok im not just going to dig through your code and write you a solution with no effort other than code dumping on your part. I doubt anyone else will either

Comment: well its bacically just this.....CourseInfo Exams = new CourseInfo(Code, Name, Type, Level, Faculty, Day, Session);
            Exams.setCourseCode(Code);
            Exams.setCourseName(Name);
            Exams.setCourseType(Type);
            Exams.setCourseLevel(Level);
            Exams.setFaculty(Faculty);
            Exams.setDay(Day);
            Exams.setSession(Session);.......the code is attcahed to a gui and there is a seach button and in the search button and when someone enters a course it brings up all it credentials

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

use the below code

```
Map <String, CourseInfo> courseMap = new HashMap<String, CourseInfo>();
```

This will define a map to store CourseInfo objects against key, you can use courseName as key. Below code can be used to add an entry to this map.

courseMap.put(Name,Exams);  // here Name is CourseName.

Now for Searching you can directly use courseMap.get(Name), this will return the entry stored in this map, against the courseName.

You can learn more about maps at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: kk i ama going to check it out and get back to you thanks

Answer (score 0):

List is not the appropriate Data Structure for your requirement.

You can use a Map and and add the records against a unique key. CourseCode or CourseName can be used as keys and you can store the complete object against this key.

Comment: okay understood but i am still relativity new to coding in java so how would i go about doing that?